# Image view relative position

Tags: android-imageview

I'm new to Android programming and I'm facing a problem: I don't know how to set the position of an imageView over another imageView. I want the position to be relative, maybe with percentages, to maintain the aspect on different screens or in both landscape and portrait.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

to place an Image over another use relativelayout as the root layout for both image views. This will make both image views start at the same coordinate and you can flexibly arrange them as you like.

example :

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

        >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/videoImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/playVideo"
        android:src="@drawable/play_"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Alternatively you can use frame layout.

Comment: I would need the second image to be placed at a specific position on the first one, but using percentages, because after that, I want to move the second picture over the first one, on a path. How could I do that? :D